# Instagram iPhone share image

Tags: ios, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying share image to Instagram. Documentation (https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) says about UTI "com.instagram.exclusivegram" and image extension "igo" for show Instagram only. But UIDocumentInteractionController shows many options for me. Not only Instagram. Have any ways to share directly to Instagram? (see single option in UIDocumentInteractionController)

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *docInteraction=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@".../image.igo"]];
docInteraction.UTI=@"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
BOOL presented=[docInteraction presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-1, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)
                                                  inView:self.view
                                                animated:YES];
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Eob.png)

Comment: try this it's open instagram direct   NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@",asset.localIdentifier]];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
        }
        else {
            
            NSLog (@"Instagram not found");
                 }

Answer (score 0):

Use this below class to share in **Instagram** And it is 100% working.

**File Name : InstagramSharing.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InstagramSharing : NSObject <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
+ (InstagramSharing*)sharedData;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;

-(void)instaGramWallPost:(NSString *)imgName andExt:(NSString *)ext inViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end
```

**File Name : InstagramSharing.m**

```
#import "InstagramSharing.h"


@implementation InstagramSharing
+ (id) sharedData
    {
        static InstagramSharing *singletonInstance = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            if(!singletonInstance) {
                singletonInstance = [[InstagramSharing alloc] init];
            }
        });

        return singletonInstance;
    }

-(NSString*) getFilePath:(NSString *)fileName{
        //    NSString *searchFilename = @"hello.pdf"; // name of the PDF you are searching for

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory];

        NSString *documentsSubpath;
        while (documentsSubpath = [direnum nextObject])
        {
            if (![documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent isEqual:fileName]) {
                continue;
            }

            NSLog(@"found %@", documentsSubpath);
        }
        return documentsSubpath;
    }

-(void)instaGramWallPost:(NSString *)imgName andExt:(NSString *)ext inViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgName  ofType:ext];
        NSURL *myURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
        UIImage *imgShare = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
        {
            UIImage *imageToUse = imgShare;
            NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
            NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.igo"];
            NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUse);
            [imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
            NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];

            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgName ofType:ext];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

            self.documentController=[[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
            self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
            self.documentController.delegate = self;
            self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing"], @"InstagramCaption", nil];
            self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
            UIViewController *vc = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
            [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:viewController.view animated:YES];
        }
        else {
            //            DisplayAlertWithTitle(@"Instagram not found", @"")
            NSLog(@"no image found");
        }
    }



@end
```

**How To use**

On Share action call below line

```
[[InstagramSharing sharedData] instaGramWallPost:@"nature1" andExt:@"jpeg" inViewController:self];
```

Comment: No. It's present dialog with few applications. Not only Instagram.

Comment: @user3026863 Didn't get you.